# calculate work hours in each day using mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate work hours in each day using  MySQL. I show many hours calculate solution but none of them fit to my requirement. In my table I don't have in our out field. I have to consider first entry as in and second as out and calculate working hours according to it.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `timesheet` (
  `MachineNo` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Empcardno` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Date` date  NOT NULL,
  `Time` time  NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `timesheet` 
(`MachineNo`, `Empcardno`, `Date`,`Time`) VALUES
    (01,    5,  '2020-05-22',   '18:15:54'),    
    (01,    5,  '2020-05-22',   '14:46:47'),
    (01,    5,  '2020-05-22',   '14:26:05'),
    (01,    5,  '2020-05-22',   '09:26:30'),
    (01,    5,  '2020-05-21',   '18:15:45'),
    (01,    5,  '2020-05-21',   '14:48:39'),
    (01,    5,  '2020-05-21',   '14:29:55'),
    (01,    5,  '2020-05-21',   '09:37:49');
```

[MySql fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b3d98/7)

I have tried the following query but it gives me only total hours between max and min time. It does not consider all the in out values. I want to consider time between all in and out point.

```
SELECT
  Empcardno,min(Time),
  max(Time),
  TIMEDIFF(max(Time),
  min(Time)) As Diff_Value
FROM
  timesheet
GROUP BY
  DATE(Date),Empcardno
```

Result

```
   Empcardno    Date       min(Time)    max(Time)   Diff_Value
    5         2020-05-21    09:37:49    18:15:45    08:37:56
    5         2020-05-22    09:26:30    18:15:54    08:49:24
```

But i want to calculate time as time between this two

```
 (01,    5,  '2020-05-21',   '14:29:55'),
 (01,    5,  '2020-05-21',   '09:37:49');
```

and

```
(01,    5,  '2020-05-21',   '18:15:45'),
(01,    5,  '2020-05-21',   '14:48:39'),
```

Comment: What are your expected results for this query?

Comment: How about a PL/SQL procedure to get your answer, sort records by (Empcardno, Date & then Time); then process each consecutive pair to get your time-diff ( hence work hours for each emp#/day)

Comment: this query display Diff_Value  08:37:56 for 2020-05-21 but actually i want calculate  as  09:37:49  as in time and 14:29:55 as out time again 14:48:39 as in time and 18:15:45 as out time  on 2020-05-21 now when i calculate it like i describe it shows me different hours

Comment: @SparKot i dont have knowledge about PL/SQL procedure

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky problem to solve without window functions... Basically you need to generate row numbers for each entry for each machine on each date. Then you can combine the odd and even rows to generate a time difference which can be summed to generate the total time for the day. To do this, I've converted the times on odd rows to negative, so that when that value is added to the next value (from the even row), we get the difference between the two.

```
SELECT MachineNo, Empcardno, Date, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(tsecs)) AS total_time
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN MachineNo = @mn AND Empcardno = @en AND `Date` = @dt
              THEN @rn := @rn + 1
              ELSE @rn := 1
         END AS rn,
         @mn := MachineNo AS MachineNo, @en := Empcardno AS Empcardno, 
         @dt := `Date` AS `Date`,
         CASE WHEN @rn % 2 = 1 THEN -TIME_TO_SEC(`Time`)
              ELSE TIME_TO_SEC(`Time`)
         END AS tsecs
  FROM timesheet
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @mn := 0, @en := 0, @dt := '', @rn := 0) init
  ORDER BY Date, Time
) t
GROUP BY MachineNo, Empcardno, Date
```

Output:

```
MachineNo   Empcardno   Date        total_time
1           5           2020-05-21  08:19:12
1           5           2020-05-22  08:28:42
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b3d98/35)

Comment: it's what i need

Comment: I understand that you would use window functions for 8+, but, as written, is this method safe for 8+ ? I just tested it, and it worked, but there's something about where the ORDER BY occurs that doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: @Strawberry this query has many issues for 8.0+, not least of which is the `ORDER BY` in the subquery which MySQL may choose to ignore (although as you say, it still seems to respect it), but also the fact that the use of variables in this manner is deprecated and may be removed in a later version. Given how much simpler this query is to write with window functions, I would hope that no-one would use it (and hence my comment right at the beginning). If you think it could use some more words to that effect let me know...

Comment: @Nick is there any other way to solve this problem without user-defined variables

Comment: @HiteshTripathi I saw your other question. I'm pretty sure it is solvable without variables, but I don't have time right now to work on an answer. If you don't have an answer when I'm next on, I'll try to give you one.